# Using "and" at the end of list which has another item with "and" inside

Tags: grammar, expressions, commas

I have a list like this.

> *His topic of interest are GIS, automation and image and data fusion.*

Here, the last item name "image and data fusion" is a single item. Is my writing correct?

Comment: You could use an ampersand(&) in place of the last 'and' to indicate (more explicitly than without) unity between the two entities as a single item in the list.  Alternatively an Oxford comma after the second-last item could do the trick.   Also, "topic" should be plural unless the entire list is actually meant purposely as one unit of mutually-bound items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "and" to end a list with an "and" phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161266/using-and-to-end-a-list-with-an-and-phrase) Or [Can you use two_and_'s in a noun phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100299/can-you-use-two-ands-in-a-sentence)

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this is the use of the "Oxford comma" before the 'and' which ends the list as opposed to the 'and' joining the parts of the final item in the list. This gives you "His topics of interest are GIS, automation, and image and data fusion." The "Oxford comma" makes clear which 'and' ends the list and which combines two components of an item in the list

Answer (score 0):

Given that the term "image and data" is an established term, especially in the fields that it concerns, it can be left as is. One might become convinced of this fact through a perusal of this [Google page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22image%20and%20data%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), which contains numerous instances of its use.

*From the mentioned page*

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Design_of_a_Medical_Image_Data_Warehouse/6_LqzkuFAL4C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22image+and+data%22&dq=%22image+and+data%22&printsec=frontcover)) The image and data analysis component contains algorithms for searching the data warehouse to analyze image data and associated clinical and laboratory findings

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ground_based_Image_and_Data_Acquisition/1VApAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22image+and+data%22&dq=%22image+and+data%22&printsec=frontcover)) Vermont was undergoing an upgrade to its ground based image and data collection system .